# Как присвоить всем ссылкам в списке кроме выделенной нужный класc?

Tags: меню, javascript, классы

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть список с ссылками.

**Сделано следующее:** При нажатии на ссылку меняется стиль на активный, при повторном нажатии на эту же ссылку когда она активна стиль меняется на прежний или сбрасывается - это так и надо. При такой реализации, нажав на первую а затем на вторую ссылку - они обе будут активными... и т.д. с каждой ссылкой.

***Надо сделать так, чтобы при любом последующем нажатии на другую ссылку была активной только нажатая! Т.е сбросить классы для остальных ссылок в списке! Вот!***

```
<div class="hlink">
    <ul class="">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="all.className('hlinkPress') = ''; this.className = (this.className == '' ? 'hlinkPress' : '')"><i class="icon-building icon-large"></i>Первая ссылка</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="this.className = (this.className == '' ? 'hlinkPress' : '')">Вторая ссылка</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="this.className = (this.className == '' ? 'hlinkPress' : '')">Третья ссылка</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="this.className = (this.className == '' ? 'hlinkPress' : '')">Четвертая ссылка</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="this.className = (this.className == '' ? 'hlinkPress' : '')">Пятая ссылка</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: лучше в отдельный скрипт вынесите обработчик, а классом лучше манипулировать через [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

Comment: Спасибо! А по подробнее?

Comment: * [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode)

 * [Node.childnodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes)

 * [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

готовый пример я  только-что писал с использованием jQuery, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3mD5X/ и поверьте мне, лучше писать с jQuery чем то как оно написано у вас сейчас.

[тут с переключением класса](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3mD5X/1/)

Comment: @eicto! Спасибо огромное, особенно последнее... прямо мысли читаете... так и нужно было с контентом, просто не написал про это!